# Android: Exit activity while it is created

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

Suppose I have code like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_msmap);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    if (mMap == null) {
      return;
    }
```

Before I start the activity I have checked google maps libraries are available. However, if there is no sim card / internet connectivity mMap still returns null.

One would think this works since the Google maps / Google play actually shows an error with "not available" with an OK button. But if one clicks it, the app hangs...

So rather, when mMap == null, I would like to simply exit the activity constructor showing an error, and then return to the prior activity. Is there any way to do that gracefully in some way?

Comment: Try calling finish() when you want to exit

Comment: I think there must be somehing unusual with with the maps API. Now I immediately get the "app hangs" dialog (which I before first got efter clicking the Google Play "ok" button).

Comment: Nevermind. I just need to use return; after finish() of course. It works! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `finish()` would exit the `Activity`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_msmap);
  setUpMapIfNeeded();
  if (mMap == null) {
    finish();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this was the first response, so I set this as the right answer. (Just a quick note: To avoid having rest of the method executed, one should still call return; as well.)

Answer (score 1):

What about calling `finish()` within the activity, e.g.

```
if (mMap== null){
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `finish()` when you want to exit:

```
  if (mMap == null) {
    finish();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_msmap);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    if (mMap == null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dlgAlert.setMessage("Whatever your error is");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("Title");
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
            }
        });
        dlgAlert.create().show();
    }
}
```